# Update panel reload entire page - Ajax not working

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I use master page concepts for my application.I have following code in aspx page

I have a gridview and a textbox inside and I am binding this gridview from codebehind ( based on db value, I will have many rows in client side). Whenever I enter a value in textbox the entire page loads and ajax is not working. What is the mistake in this code. I have already added scriptmanager in master page. Its always loading entire page.As it is master page concepts, the following code are inside contentplaceholder

```
                <tbody>


                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPnl" UpdateMode="Always" runat="server">

                        <ContentTemplate>


                            <asp:GridView ID="grdBOQ" Width="100%" ShowFooter="true" OnRowDataBound="gvBOQDetails_OnRowDataBound" OnRowCommand="grdBOQ_RowCommand" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server" CssClass="gvBOQdatatable">

                                <Columns>

                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sl No:">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <%#(grdBOQ.PageSize * grdBOQ.PageIndex) + grdBOQ.Rows.Count + 1%>
                                        </ItemTemplate>


                                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="40px" Wrap="False" />
                                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                        <FooterTemplate>
                                            <div style="text-align: center;">
                                                <%#(grdBOQ.PageSize * grdBOQ.PageIndex) + grdBOQ.Rows.Count + 1%>
                                            </div>
                                        </FooterTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item ID"  >
                                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="HiddenCol" />
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblItem_ID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BOQ_ITEM_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" CssClass="HiddenCol" />
                                        <FooterTemplate>
                                            <div style="text-align: center;">
                                                <asp:Label runat="server" Text='' ID="lblItemID"></asp:Label>
                                            </div>
                                        </FooterTemplate>
                                        <FooterStyle CssClass="HiddenCol" />

                                    </asp:TemplateField>


                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Section">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BOQ_SECTION") %>' ID="lblSection"></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <FooterTemplate>
                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlBOQSection" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlSectionItem_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                                onmouseover="this.size=5;" onmouseout="this.size=1;"
                                                Style="max-height: 100px; overflow: auto;" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server">
                                            </asp:DropDownList>


                                        </FooterTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Category Name">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Category_Name") %>' ID="lblCategoryName"></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                        <FooterTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label runat="server" Text='' ID="lblCatName"></asp:Label>

                                        </FooterTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>


                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Category Description">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>' ID="lblCategoryDescription"></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>

                                        <FooterTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label runat="server" Text='' ID="lblCatDesc"></asp:Label>

                                        </FooterTemplate>

                                    </asp:TemplateField>


                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtQuantity_TextChanged" class="form-control" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("QUANTITY") %>' Style="width: 80px" MaxLength="8"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </ItemTemplate>


                                        <FooterTemplate>
                                            <div style="text-align: center">
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantityDyn" class="txtlbl" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtQuantityDyn_TextChanged" ReadOnly="true" Style="width: 80px" Text='0' runat="server" />
                                            </div>
                                        </FooterTemplate>

                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Unit">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UOM_Name") %>' ID="lblUnit"></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>


                                        <FooterTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label runat="server" Text='' ID="lblSectionUnit"></asp:Label>

                                        </FooterTemplate>

                                    </asp:TemplateField>


                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Unit Rate">
                                        <ItemTemplate>

                                            <asp:TextBox ID="lblUnitRate" class="txtlbl" ReadOnly="true" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SellingPrice_Per_UOM")  %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                        </ItemTemplate>

                                        <FooterTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxSectionUR" class="txtlbl" ReadOnly="true" Text="0.00" runat="server" />
                                        </FooterTemplate>

                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total">
                                        <ItemTemplate>

                                            <asp:TextBox ID="lblTotalPrice" class="txtlbl" ReadOnly="true" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TOTAL") %>'></asp:TextBox>



                                        </ItemTemplate>

                                        <FooterTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxURT" class="txtlbl" ReadOnly="true" Text='0.00' runat="server" />
                                        </FooterTemplate>


                                    </asp:TemplateField>



                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">


                                        <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                                        <FooterTemplate>
                                            <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" Text="Add New BOQ" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>" CommandName="addNew" />
                                        </FooterTemplate>

                                    </asp:TemplateField>



                                </Columns>

                            </asp:GridView>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Textbox changed code

```
protected void txtQuantity_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Session[clsCommon.SESSION_USER_ROLE_ID].ToString() == clsCommon.gConst_UserRole_PM.ToString())
            {

                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "text", "OptionHide()", true);
            }
            if (Session["RowCount"]==null)
            { 
            Session["RowCount"] = grdBOQ.Rows.Count;
            }
            else
            { 

            int rowCount = grdBOQ.Rows.Count;
            }
            TextBox thisTextBox = (TextBox)sender;
            GridViewRow currentRow = (GridViewRow)thisTextBox.Parent.Parent;
            int rowindex = 0;
            rowindex = currentRow.RowIndex;
            Label txt = (Label)currentRow.FindControl("lblItem_ID");
            int val = Convert.ToInt32(txt.Text);

            DataSet dsBOMInvoice = new DataSet();
            objInvoiceUser.P_BOQ_ID = val;

            dsBOMInvoice = objInvoiceUser.GetBOMValues();



            decimal bomQuantity = 0;
            decimal bomPrice;



            if (btnobcInvoice.Visible == true)
            {
                clsContractorInvoiceEdit objConInvEdit = new clsContractorInvoiceEdit();

                objInvoiceUser.P_BOQ_ID = val;
                objInvoiceUser.P_ASSIGN_INVOICE_ORDER_ID = intAssignOrderID;
                DataSet dsBOMNew = objInvoiceUser.GetAllPMBOM();
                var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
                string bom_section;
                int bom_new_count = dsBOMNew.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
                decimal result = 0.000M;
                Session["result"] = "0.00";
                if(bom_new_count>=1)
                {

                    bom_section = dsBOMNew.Tables[0].Rows[0]["BOM_SECTION"].ToString().ToLower();
                    decimal value = Convert.ToDecimal(thisTextBox.Text);

                    objConInvEdit.P_BOQ = val;
                    objConInvEdit.P_BOM = bom_section;
                    objConInvEdit.P_Quantity = value;
                    objConInvEdit.P_order_ID = intAssignOrderID;
                    objConInvEdit.P_type = 1;
                    objConInvEdit.P_mode = 1;
                     result = objConInvEdit.InsertUPdateConINVEdit();

                     Session["result"] = result;

                }

                //    Response.Write("<script>alert('Hello');</script>");


            }

            else
            {

                Session["result"] = thisTextBox.Text;

            }


            if (dsBOMInvoice.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow dr in dsBOMInvoice.Tables[0].Rows)
                {


                    var BOQ_ID = dr["BOM_ID"].ToString();


                    foreach (GridViewRow BOMrow in grdBOM.Rows)
                    {


                        Label lblBOMItem_ID = (Label)BOMrow.FindControl("lblBOMItem_ID");
                        if (lblBOMItem_ID.Text == BOQ_ID)
                        {

                            TextBox txtBOMQuantity = (TextBox)BOMrow.FindControl("txtBOMQuantity");
                            txtBOMQuantity.Text = Session["result"].ToString();


                        }


                    }


                }

            }
            decimal ld_tot_tots = 0, TotalbomPrice = 0;
            foreach (GridViewRow BOMrows in grdBOM.Rows)
            {
                decimal ld_tots = 0;

                string BOmQuantity = ((TextBox)BOMrows.FindControl("txtBOMQuantity")).Text;   //tiru   
                if (BOmQuantity != string.Empty && BOmQuantity != null && BOmQuantity != "")
                {

                    bomQuantity = decimal.Parse(((TextBox)BOMrows.FindControl("txtBOMQuantity")).Text);
                }

                //bomQuantity = decimal.Parse(((TextBox)BOMrows.FindControl("txtBOMQuantity")).Text);
                bomPrice = decimal.Parse(((TextBox)BOMrows.FindControl("lblBOMUnitRate")).Text);

                TotalbomPrice = (bomQuantity * bomPrice);
                TextBox totalBOM = (TextBox)BOMrows.FindControl("lblBOMTotalPrice");
                totalBOM.Text = TotalbomPrice.ToString();


                ld_tots = Convert.ToDecimal(((TextBox)BOMrows.FindControl("lblBOMTotalPrice")).Text);
                ld_tot_tots = ld_tot_tots + ld_tots;

            }
            // grandBOMTotal = Convert.ToDecimal(ld_tot_tots) + Convert.ToDecimal(TotalbomPrice);
            lblBOMtotal.Text = Convert.ToDecimal(ld_tot_tots).ToString();

            lblGrandtotal.Text = Decimal.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(lblBOMtotal.Text), Convert.ToDecimal(lblBOQTotal.Text)).ToString();



            lblFinalGrandTotal.Text = Decimal.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(lblGrandtotal.Text), Convert.ToDecimal(lblAllGrandtotal.Text)).ToString();


            //BOQ - first Grid

            decimal addQuantity = 0; decimal Quantity = 0; //tiru
            decimal price, TotalPrice, addprice = 0;

            foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in grdBOQ.Rows)
            {
                string quantity_val = ((TextBox)gvRow.FindControl("txtQuantity")).Text;  //tiru
                if (quantity_val != string.Empty && quantity_val != null && quantity_val != "")
                {

                    Quantity = decimal.Parse(((TextBox)gvRow.FindControl("txtQuantity")).Text);
                }
                //decimal Quantity = decimal.Parse(((TextBox)gvRow.FindControl("txtQuantity")).Text);   

                price = decimal.Parse(((TextBox)gvRow.FindControl("lblUnitRate")).Text);

                addQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(((TextBox)grdBOQ.FooterRow.FindControl("txtQuantityDyn")).Text);
                addprice = decimal.Parse(((TextBox)grdBOQ.FooterRow.FindControl("TextBoxSectionUR")).Text);

                TextBox total = (TextBox)gvRow.FindControl("lblTotalPrice");

                TotalPrice = (Quantity * price);

                total.Text = TotalPrice.ToString();



                grandBOQTotal = Decimal.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(grandBOQTotal), Convert.ToDecimal(TotalPrice));


            }


            TotalPrice = (addQuantity * addprice);
            grandBOQTotal = Decimal.Add(grandBOQTotal, TotalPrice);

            lblBOQTotal.Text = Convert.ToDecimal(grandBOQTotal).ToString();
            grandBOQTotal = 0;
            lblGrandtotal.Text = Decimal.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(lblBOMtotal.Text), Convert.ToDecimal(lblBOQTotal.Text)).ToString();

            lblFinalGrandTotal.Text = Decimal.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(lblGrandtotal.Text), Convert.ToDecimal(lblAllGrandtotal.Text)).ToString();


        }
```

Comment: I think `AutoPostBack` of your text box is `true` change it to `false`

Comment: But Whenever I enter a value in textbox, it doesn't fetch values from server after removing autopostBack

Comment: So please provide your back-end code to fetching text box value, is it in `text_change`?

Comment: yes it is inside text_change. I am doing some calculation based on the value entered in the text box and return to grid and showing in a label

Comment: I have updated OP.kindly look

Comment: Your provided code can't give us the clue, the problem may depends on something else

Comment: I have updated ,please check OP

Comment: No the problem is refreshing page after `textbox_change` not text box change itself, yes ?

Comment: when I change textbox, I am getting values from serverside but entire page loads. If autopost back is false, not getting value from server

Comment: Just for test, remove that `scriptManager` in master page and put it in child page and do the test.

Comment: No change at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170130/discussion-between-aria-and-aniltc).

Answer (score 0):

I hope the solution would be removing `UpdateMode` then the first solution which came in my mind is :

1- Change `UpdateMode` to `Conditional` and and set `ChildrenAsTriggers` to `false` so you should have something like:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPnl" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
           ......
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtQuantity_TextChanged" class="form-control" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("QUANTITY") %>' Style="width: 80px" MaxLength="8"></asp:TextBox>
   ........
   ......
```

2- An the second: If the first does not work then remove `UpdateMode` of update panel and define a trigger for that text box so the code be something like

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPnl" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtQuantity_TextChanged" ....
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="txtQuantity" EventName="TextChanged" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
            .......
```

Hope these will help you.

Comment: I tried both - not working. When I added triggers getting following error "A control with ID 'txtQuantity' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'updPnl'."

Comment: I tried this solution early for the above error  but not working and entire page loads. I used textbox instead of linkbutton https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Assign-PostBack-Trigger-Full-PostBack-for-LinkButton-inside-GridView-within-AJAX-UpdatePanel-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: I suggest you to put update panel inside the grid view and then try that two solutions, I think this work.